# Can't find the way to save fragment states

Tags: android, android-fragments

The problem is the following, I have a navigation drawer with three fragments A, B and C. Within fragment B I have a ViewPager which in turn has 3 fragments but let's call it B-1, B-2 and B-3. I was reading a lot and trying but I can not do that when I navigate between the navigationDrawer I save the status of all the fragments are A, B, C and all of the ViewPager.

I tried with the freezeText attribute in the xml, keeping everything in a list within my viewpager (this for the 3 fragments of the viewpager, obviously) and I also tried with the savedinstancestate method but I can not get what I want, below I leave my code of the viewpager your adapter I have it in a separate class but it has no code that is not normal manual, if at least we can make it work that would be a breakthrough that I just could not achieve. Thank you

fragment that contains my viewPager:

```
public class CargarStocksFragment extends Fragment {
  ..
  ..
  private List<Fragment> fragmentList;
  ..
  ..
  @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("Lista", (Serializable) fragmentList);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState!=null)
        fragmentList= (List<Fragment>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("Lista");
    else
        fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
}
..
..
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new ArticuloFragment();
}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what you tried and what was the result. E.g., if you used saved instance state, you should be able to debug and see exactly what you're getting handed back on restore.

Comment: just now i can't response why i changed the architecture of my app, now i testing with sharedPreferences and the results are good, but still have errors on Save the data